# Solve a system of many algebraic equations in Matlab

Tags: matlab, equations

I am trying to solve a system of nine algebraic equations in MATLAB of the following form:

```
eq1 = x1 * 3.12091E-17 * 10.96 * exp(x2 + x3 * 4.96) - 1765;

eq2 = x1 * 3.12091E-17 * 5.08 * exp(x2 + x3 * 5.09) - 720;

eq3 = x1 * 3.12091E-17 * 57.2 * exp(x2 + x3 * 5.22) - 7133;

eq4 = x1 * 3.12091E-17 * 1.08 * exp(x2 + x3 * 5.3) - 123;

eq5 = x1 * 3.12091E-17 * 5.01 * exp(x2 + x3 * 5.32) - 565;

eq6 = (100 - x1) * 4.91606E-18 * 0.096 * exp(x2 + x3 * 6.61) - 8;

eq7 = (100 - x1) * 4.91606E-18 * 0.318 * exp(x2 + x3 * 6.64) - 28;

eq8 = (100 - x1) * 4.91606E-18 * 0.054 * exp(x2 + x3 * 6.66) - 4;

eq9 = (100 - x1) * 4.91606E-18 * 0.832 * exp(x2 + x3 * 6.9) - 57;
```

This system has only three unknowns in nine equations. I have tried to solve it using inbuilt MATLAB solvers, but unfortunately nothing worked. The correct values of the unknowns are: `x1=4.6; x2=47; x3=-1.2`.

What are your ideas on what is possibly wrong that MATLAB cannot solve this system?

Regards,
I.M.

Comment: First of all which methods have you tried. Second of all, you are multiplying by very low numbers which is going to cause serious problems with floating point problems.

Comment: Also, you have `x1` listed twice in your desired solutions.

Comment: Okay, I just tested it and you definitely have floating point issues which I don't think you're going to get to work in MATLAB. You have `10^-18` and `e^40` in the same line which is not going to work out well on a 64 bit machine..

Comment: Hello Durkee, thank you for your comment. I have corrected the misspelled variable, thank you for pointing out. Regarding the solvers I used - I have tried linear and nonlinear solvers, in particular: linsolve, matrix division and nonlinear solver fsolve. Besides I used numeric solving by the means of fminsearch. Do you think the main problem is caused by the presence of very low numbers in the equations?

Comment: Very low and very high numbers combined. MATLAB typically uses 64-bit floating point which means that there is a limited amount of precision. If you type `eps(exp(40))` into the command window, you can see how much distance is between each possible number that can be stored. As you can see, this value is much greater than `10^-18` which means that there is simply not enough precision to do your calculations. At this point, it rounds the computations to `~±.5*eps(exp(40))` which is huge and causes large errors

Comment: @Durkee, actually, the accuracy is more like `±eps(1e-20*exp(40))`, which is in the order of 1e-19. Considering all the steps needed (with a lot of handwaving argumentation), I'd say < 1e-10 should be possible. In any case, more than sufficient to solve the problem; see also my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you have 3 unknowns in 9 equations then your problem is [**overdetermined**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overdetermined_system). If your system has a solution, then some equations must be linear combinations of others - in short you only need 3 (linearly independent) equations to solve for 3 variables.

Next, as mentioned in the comments, you are going to hit floating point issues when using numbers as small as `10^-18` and as large as `e^40`, especially within the same expression! You can see that the accuracy isn't high enough with a simple test

```
exp(40) + 1e-18 > exp(40) % Returns false, i.e. not enough accuracy for additional term 

eps(exp(40)) % Gives smallest distance to next number, returns 32. 
             % This is many orders of magnitude larger than 10^-18!
```

Once you have resolved those issues, you should look at [`fsolve`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fsolve.html), which is MATLAB's solver for nonlinear systems of equations from some initial guess.

Comment: Hello Wolfie, thank you for your comment. Indeed, as I understood one of the reasons may be due to the presence of very low numbers. Regarding you first point that I may need only 3 independent equations - how do I construct them from my nine?

Comment: @Durkee you can have as many as you want, as long as they don't conflict. Simplest example is 1 unknown with 2 equations. `x = 1, x = 2` solving for `x` is impossible! This is why I said they must be linearly dependent, i.e. `x = 1, 2x = 2` solving for `x` is possible. This is why I linked to further info about overdetermined systems.

Comment: @I.M. we would need more information about how these equations are constructed. If they are linearly dependant then you can just arbitrarily choose 3 which aren't. If they aren't, then your system does not have a solution (see the linked wiki article).

Comment: Indeed these equations are linearly dependent, however even for 3 arbitrarily selected using fsolve does not produce any result - only the message "no solutions found"...

Comment: Right, so you've fixed problem one (overdetermined system) and leapt to the solving section without fixing problem two (the floating point issues). Try a simpler system where you know there are no floating point issues, get it working, then change the values until you get an issue. You may need to take a different approach to whatever problem you're trying to solve, like more mathematical manipulation before chucking it into MATLAB.

Answer (score 0):

I think Wolfie and Durkee are wrong here, and you simply made some other mistake not shown in the question body.

### Accuracy is not the problem

You have a multiplication of a large number by a small number. This is not usually an issue in floating point (save for under/overflow situations), it's addition/subtraction that usually causes problems.

Basically, floating point equals scientific notation in binary. Just as in normal scientific notation, floating point preserves relative accuracy indepent of the magnitude of the numbers used, because the mantissa and exponent are treated independently. A small demonstration (refer to the [IEEE/754 standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) for background):

```
% Take two random numbers from the ENTIRE range of possible doubles: 
R  = @() typecast(randi(intmax('uint32'), 1,2, 'uint32'), 'double');
R1 = R()
R2 = R()

% Their product
p1 = R1*R2

% Compute the same product, but with randomized exponents/equal mantissas
R1 = typecast(R1,'uint64');
R2 = typecast(R2,'uint64');
for bit = 64-11:64-1 % (ignore sign bit)
    R1 = bitset(R1, bit, rand() < 0.5); 
    R2 = bitset(R2, bit, rand() < 0.5); 
end
R1 = typecast(R1,'double')
R2 = typecast(R2,'double')

p2 = R1*R2

% Show binary representations of these products
dec2bin(typecast(p1,'uint64'), 64)
dec2bin(typecast(p2,'uint64'), 64)
```

which gives, for example:

```
R1 =
    1.455811561734462e+106
R2 =
    2.491861453769942e-128
p1 =
     3.627680714638727e-22
R1 =
    2.773851093980602e+246
R2 =
    2.835869106622333e-287
p2 =
     7.866278623790151e-41
ans =
    '0011101101111011011010001111010001111011100010001110101000000000'
ans =
    '0011011110011011011010001111010001111011100010001110101000000000'
```

Ignoring bit 0 (the sign bit), these two strings demonstrate that only the first 11 bits (the exponent) differ, but the rest (the mantissa) is *identical*. This means that `p1` and `p2` are both the best possible representation of the desired product `R1*R2` in floating point, and the magnitudes of `R1` and `R2` have *zero* effect on the accuracy (unless the exponent under/overflows).

### Solving the equations

Now, back to your question. First off, I'm very curious how you managed to solve a set of nonlinear equations with solvers for linear systems :)

Also, when I implement your equations and substitute the values you give, I get a vector of negative values...so I'm not sure what you're solving for here...

Anyway, I made reasonable assumptions and tried to solve your system with `fsolve`. And indeed, I found no substantial problem:

```
function X = eqs()

    % Oh just shut up, FSOLVE...
    options = optimset('TolX'     , 1e-14,...
                       'TolFun'   , 1e-14,...
                       'Algorithm', 'Levenberg-Marquardt',...
                       'Display'  , 'off');

    % Pretend we don't know a good initial value
    done = false;
    while ~done  
        try
            [X, ~, e] = fsolve(@equations, 100*randn(3,1), options);
            done = (e==1);
        catch ME
            if ~strcmp(ME.identifier, 'optimlib:levenbergMarquardt:UsrObjUndefAtX0')
                rethrow(ME); end
        end
    end

end

function Y = equations(X)

    % Static factors
    A = 3.12091e-17 * [10.96;  5.08;  57.2;  1.08; 5.01];
    B = 4.91606e-18 * [0.096; 0.318; 0.054; 0.832];
    C = [4.96; 5.09; 5.22; 5.30; 5.32; 6.61; 6.64; 6.66; 6.90];
    D = [1765; 720; 7133; 123; 565; 8; 28; 4; 57];

    % (found by running the equation with your solution, to have a complete
    % equation compatible with fsolve)
    E = [-7.087431856800463e+02
         -3.011362826270133e+02
         -3.097892400288644e+03
         -5.378653741735363e+01
         -2.515404691148800e+02
         -3.826949873156565e+00
         -1.466555675930393e+01
         -1.789357783939141e+00
         -3.146292129042946e+01];

    % Value of the equations at current X
    Y = [A.*X(1).*ones(5,1); B.*(100-X(1)).*ones(4,1)] .* ...
        exp(X(2) + C*X(3)) - D - E;

end
```

Results:

```
>> eqs()
ans =
     4.599999930381616e+00
     4.700000001536806e+01
    -1.200000000274661e+00
```

The only problem here might be the speed. I've used a very simple global search routine: iteratively taking random starting values until some combination of them causes `fsolve` to converge. In your problem's context, you might be able to make more reasonable and accurate estimates, reducing the computation time.

Comment: You might as well include your global optimizer as a link. I've used it before and it works well. How does it work if you do not know the error values at the optimal solution?

Comment: @Durkee: meh, that's a bit overkill for this problem. I guess the OP knows a bit more about the problem, perhaps enough to guide this simple brute-force approach a bit better

Comment: Hello Rody, thank you for such an explicit example. Indeed, I did not think of an iterative routine to choosing the starting values. Actually it works in my case best of all, because in real life situations the starting values are unknown (these equations are from radioactivity measurements). Thank you!

Comment: @I.M. hmmm but surely you can come up with a range for `X` better than my `100*randn(3,1)`?

Comment: Rody, x1 is always in the range between 0.1 and 100; x2 is always positive and lies between 10 and 100; x3 is always negative. How do I deal with the vector E when I do not know the solution in advance?

Comment: This was exactly the point I was trying to make: your equations carry insufficient information to render them into a formula for `fsolve`. Substituting the values for `x` you gave results in the vector `E`, which is not very special in itself: substituting *any* `x` will produce another vector.  You need numeric values for `eq1`...`eq9` before you can solve the equations for `x`. Put more simply, you've asked this: `eq1 = 3*x + 4*y + z`; solve for `x`, `y` and `z`...it can't be done unless you *also* specify `eq1 = 3.2` and constraints on `x`, `y`, `z`.

Comment: Rody, I have implemented your code in my version of matlab (R2016b) but the code does not work due to absence of Datafeed toolbox (for eqs). I am quite new to matlab, is it possible to implement your code without the eqs?

Comment: Just copy-paste *all* the code shown above in a file called `eqs.m`, place that file somewhere on the MATLAB search path (or just navigate to it inside MATLAB), and then you should be able to run `eqs` on the MATLAB [command line (I chose a name for the function that apparently is already used in the datafeed toolbox)

Comment: Rody, I need to add to the code a part in which matlab first opens a file to read the values for static variables (in the current case they were predefined), how do I correctly add this module to the code? It should be inside the function eqs or before it?

Comment: Rody, the code does not work if instead of the static numbers (like those very small ones) I introduce variables that read those values from a file. What may be the problem?